# iOS UIBezierPath is upside down when rendered using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

A track path is defined using data points with an origin (0,0) at top/left.
From these points a `UIBezierPath` is created.

The cars movement along the path is given as distance, from which percent is calculated.
A category on `UIBezierPath` provides the coordinates for the car along the path.

```
#import "UIBezierPath-Points.h"
CGPoint currCoordinates = [self.trackPath pointAtPercent:percent withSlope:nil];
```

The problem is that SpriteKit renders the track path upside-down.

In a `SKScene` class …

```
SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
[shapeNode setPath:self.trackPath.CGPath];            <== path is rendered upside-down?
[shapeNode setPath:cgPath];
[shapeNode setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self addChild:shapeNode];
```

I have attempted various transforms on the `UiBezierPath`, but cannot get the coordinates to convert to `SpriteKit` coordinates which I believe are centre based.

Does anyone know how to convert from `UIBezierPath` coordinates to `SpriteKit` (SKScene) coordinates?

*don't have enuf reputation to post image.

Comment: **how to convert from UIBezierPath coordinates to SpriteKit (SKScene) coordinates?** good question

Comment: It looks as if you are setting another path `cgPath` after setting the first one `self.trackPath.CGPath`... so might be a mistake. `self.trackPath.CGPath` won't ever be used.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me was thinking that it was self-explanatory.

from [Source](https://github.com/erica/iOS-Drawing/blob/master/C01/Quartz%20Book%20Pack/Bezier/BezierUtils.m)

```
void ApplyCenteredPathTransform(UIBezierPath *path, CGAffineTransform transform)
{
    CGRect rect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path.CGPath); 
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, center.x, center.y);
    t = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, t);
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, -center.x, -center.y);
    [path applyTransform:t];
}

void ScalePath(UIBezierPath *path, CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy)
{
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sx, sy);
    ApplyCenteredPathTransform(path, t);
}
```

then

```
ScalePath(path, 1.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: Excuse me was thinking that it was self-explanatory.